# How to prevent multiple calls of a custom event handler when using the Observer Pattern in jQuery

Tags: jquery, event-handling, observer-pattern

I am using jQuery to implement the observer pattern.  I am triggering a custom event on $('body *') because it is not know what elements will respond to the event.  That is, I want to enable my fellow developers to add code to respond to the event without me having to know about it.  The problem I am encountering is that any child elements of an element bound to the custom event execute the handler.  Is there a way to make sure that these child elements do not execute the handler?  Keep in mind that I can't trigger on the element itself, because that element is unknown.  I would like to avoid having the target elements add a class if possible.

Here is some example code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $('#clickMe').click(function() {
          $('body *').trigger('myCustomEvent');
        });

        $('#someDiv').bind('myCustomEvent', function(e) {
          alert('someDiv responding to myCustomEvent');
        });

        $('#someOtherDivAddedBySomeOtherGuyLaterOn').bind('myCustomEvent', function() {
          alert('someOtherDivAddedBySomeOtherGuyLaterOn responding to myCustomEvent');
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="someDiv">
      <span>a span</span>
      <span>another span</span>
    </div>
    <div id="someOtherDivAddedBySomeOtherGuyLaterOn">
      <span>a span</span>
      <span>another span</span>
    </div>
    <p><button type="button" id="clickMe">Click Me</button></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there  is an automatic way to prevent event bubbling on child elements, but you can manually stop bubbling on known child elements.  For example:

```
$('#someDiv span').bind('myCustomEvent', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

UPDATE: Here is working code example.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script> 
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#clickMe').click(function() {
          $('body *').trigger('myCustomEvent');
        });

        $('#someDiv').bind('myCustomEvent', function(e) {
          console.log('someDiv responding to myCustomEvent');
        });

        $('#someDiv span, #someOtherDivAddedBySomeOtherGuyLaterOn span').bind('myCustomEvent', function(e) {
          e.stopPropagation();
        });

        $('#someOtherDivAddedBySomeOtherGuyLaterOn').bind('myCustomEvent', function() {
          console.log('someOtherDivAddedBySomeOtherGuyLaterOn responding to myCustomEvent');
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="someDiv">
      <span>a span</span>
      <span id="another">another span</span>
    </div>
    <div id="someOtherDivAddedBySomeOtherGuyLaterOn">
      <span>a span</span>
      <span>another span</span>
    </div>
    <p><button type="button" id="clickMe">Click Me</button></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure?  It works for me.  Check your syntax - any JS errors in your console?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your answer.  I think the solution for me is to bind the events to document.